# Is the android.intent.action.MAIN Activity launched when a BroadcastReceiver is called while the app is killed?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, android-download-manager

If I register for an Intent in the AndroidManifest.xml (specifically DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE from the DownloadManager). If this BroadcastReceiver is called while the application was previously killed, what state will the main Activity be in? Will it even be created?

Answer (score -1):

It will call whatever you define in the onReceive portion of the broadcast receiver. If you want it to call MainActivity.class then you can easily do that.